# Autofac - passing a value inside a .OnActivated Method at the Resolve time

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

i need to pass a value inside  .OnActivated  method  when i resolve an instance

```
builder.RegisterType<MyType>().PropertiesAutowired().
    .OnActivated(x => {                    
        var myValue  =    //i need to get a value passed when i call Resolve
        //do stuffs
        }
    );

var myObject = scope.Resolve<MyType>();   //<--to pass a value here
```

how to do this? i know that exist factories? does it exist a simplier way

Comment: Do you need the same value all the time or can it be different per instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two main cases:

1/Your value is static application wide

You can simply register like this

```
int dummy = 20;

builder.RegisterType<MyType>().PropertiesAutowired()
.OnActivated(x => 
{
    var myValue = dummy;
}
```

This is perfectly valid

2/You parameter is known at resolve time only

You can add your parameter as a constructor argument:

```
public class MyType
{
    private int intValue;

    public MyType(int myCustomValue)
    {
        this.intValue = myCustomValue;
    }
}
```

Then you can either build a small [Abstract Factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) or use built int Func

```
int dummy = 20;
var myObjectFactory = scope.Resolve<Func<int, MyType>>();

var myObject = myObjectFactory(dummy);
```

[Delegate Factories](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Delegate-Factories) can also help

Answer (score 0):

If the value you need to pass is a value that is being calculated on resolve time, from inside the container. You can use the `IActivatedEventArgs`.

The `e.Instance` is an object related to the registered object (`MyType` in the code below), you can do what ever you want with it.

```
.OnActivated((IActivatedEventArgs<MyType> e) =>
    {
        MyChild myChild = e.Context.Resolve<MyChild>();
        //If you has a SetChild method inside MyType class you can now use it.
        e.Instance.SetChild(myChild);
    });
```